# Passing styles to components

Tags: angular

I'm working on a "pretty select" component, and I figure once I have it working well, I'll put it up for people to review/use (which is a different thing I have to figure out). One thing I'm trying to figure out is if someone want to use my component and I want to allow them to style it, how could I do that?

I know I can make the classes/structure public and then allow users to use `/deep/` to pass in styles, but I'm noticing some priority issues there, though this seems like a more ideal method. I also know I could create an input on the component to pass in a object of styles and use use the `[ngStyle]` directive, but that could get complex, specially if the user wanted to pass the same style to multiple parts of the component.

The structure of the component is:

```
<div class="wrapper" [class.open]="showOptions">
    <ul class="options">
        <li *ngFor="let option of options" (click)="selectOption(option)">{{option.label}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="current" (click)="toggleOptions()">{{value.label}}</div>
    <div class="dropdown" (click)="toggleOptions()"></div>
</div>
```

I could attach a `[ngStyle]` to each, but that seems cumbersome. Is there a better way, or is that the best I have?

Comment: Is there a need to expose the styles via angular? I think you should put some handy CSS class selectors, so basically they can be overwritten on CSS.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear; I'll fix the question. That was my question/concern, about whether a user should use `/deep/` or pass it in. My problem with `/deep/` right now is priorities seem to be messing up.

Comment: I think you should stick with `/deep/` unless there's some specific options regarding to different styles or elements you want to implement (e.g. if there's the chance to put an icon to the right or a validation message or whatever) which in that case these options should be handled via `@Input` and so on.
What problems are you having with `/deep/` by the way?.
There's another option I think which is setting the `encapsulation` property of your `@Component` decorator to `ViewEncapsulation.None`, so basically you don't have to use `/deep/`.

Comment: Thanks. Like I mentioned, the problem I'm running into is priority. Since angular attaches a unique attribute identifier (like: `.options[_ngcontent-c8]`) to the css I add, it's ranking higher than the css being added via `/deep/`. I don't wanna turn encapsulation off, because then it could incidentally break css. If I could figure out the CSS priority issue, I'm fine with `/deep/`.

Answer (score 2):

**update**

`::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

**original**

You can use `ngStyle` as you mentioned or style them from the outside using `::ng-deep`

```
* ::ng-deep child-comp dive.wrapper {
  border: solid 3px red;
}
```

You can also use SASS and path variables to allow a user to configure SASS imports using environment variables.